# Child components not rendering when referenced dynamically in composition API

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I'm converting some components from vue 3's option API to the composition API. In this particular component I have two nested child components:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import ShiftOperation from "@/components/transformation-widgets/ShiftOperation.vue";
import RawJolt from "@/components/transformation-widgets/RawJolt.vue";

console.log([ShiftOperation, RawJolt])

...
```

From what I understand, if you're using the `setup` attribute in the script tag then all you have to do is import the component into a variable like I'm doing above and it should be available for the template without having to do anything else, like it's not like the old options api where you had to inject those components into the parent component.

Both components are imported successfully (confirmed by the console log:

[image: confirming components]

When I'm rendering out this parent component I'm using the two child components to render out an array of data where I reference the children dynamically in the template based on information in each block of data that I'm iterating over:

```
<template>
  <div class="renderer-wrapper">
    <component
        v-for="(block, index) in store.specBlocks"
        v-bind:key="index"
        :block="block"
        :index="index"
        :is="determineBlockComponent(block)"
        @block-operation-updated="updateBlock"
    >
    </component>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
// logic for determining the component to use:
export const determineBlockComponent = (block: JoltOperation) => {
  switch (block.renderComponent) {
    case 'shift':
      return 'ShiftOperation'
    default:
      return 'RawJolt'
  }
}
```

This worked fine in the options api version of it, but for some reason the components don't actually render. They show up in the elements tab:

[image: element's tab]

But they don't show up in the view. I also added a created lifecycle hook into the child components that just console.log's out saying "created X", but those hooks don't fire.

Business logic wise nothing has changed, it's just been going from option api to composition api, so I'm assuming I'm missing some key detail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `determineBlockComponent` function should not return the string but the object of the component. Replace `return 'ShiftOperation'` with `return ShiftOperation`

Comment: Fantastic!!! awesome thanks for pointing that out :clap: Do you happen to know where in the API docs that's noted? I was digging through them but couldn't seem to find it. I actually only figured out that the import was the only thing needed from a third party article https://medium.com/@miladmeidanshahi/vue3-import-and-register-components-in-composition-api-4cc36555fe19. In that I can see that it's returning the actual component and not a string, just missed that little nuance. Thanks again :bows:

Comment: Unfortunately it is not very clear from the docs. `component` `is` can receive a string or an object (component definition). If it is a string, the component must be [registered first](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#component-registration). `import`  is not registration by name even [it may look like it from the docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#local-registration)

Comment: aaah yeah that makes sense. Hmm, I wish there was a register feature or tool within the setup attribute usage of the composition API, this works for me re: returning the actual component, but the component being imported and not registered also jacks up my intellisense. I had to turn off my "import cleanup on save" feature b/c the import never got referenced in the code so the imports kept getting wiped.

Comment: What are you using? Vetur or Volar? Volar works much better and is recommended by Vue team...

Comment: Oh interesting, I'm using Vetur. I hadn't heard of Volar (I've not worked in vue in a couple of years so I'm behind on a lot). 

OH NO!!! So I'm primarily a back end java/kotlin engineer so I use intellij for most things (it's actually super nice for vue) and volar doesn't have jetbrains support :dead: :'( It's nbd to switch back to code, but man I wish I could use it in intellij

Comment: My bad, just assuming anyone working with Vue is using VS Code :) Jetbrains is cool, I'm long time Resharper user but when doing anything frontend VS Code is my choice.

Comment: Ah no worries. I def used to use Code all of the time when I was more full stack, and still use it now from time to time, but I def drank the coolaid on the jetbrains tools, especially since the company pays for the premium tooling. But yeah, I may end up switching to code for the rest of it, especially if it resolves some of these intellisense issues.